# TFS 2015 Update1: cache folder duplicated

Tags: caching, tfs

I have an issue with the TFS cache folder.
I have configured TFS to save cached data in a dedicated hard drive (*F:\TFSCache*) and I see this in the TFS Admin Console.
If I open the F:\ drive, I can see the cached data under the "proxy" folder.

All seems to work fine, but I noticed that my C:\ drive space is still used by TFS to save cached data under  "*C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services_tfs_data\1e68059b-3328-4ab3-af6e-3a068be57a6d\Proxy*"

If I compare the two folders in the two drive, they have almost same folders and all these folders have the "date modified" attribute updated with the latest date and time.

Why?
I want that TFS uses only the F:\ drive as specified in the console.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you have followed [To specify a different cache root folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/change-caching-app-tier#to-specify-a-different-cache-root-folder)

The last step is  **Delete the old cache root folder**. Otherwise, TFS will still write cache to the old folder. After deletion,  TFS will uses only the `F:\TFSCache` as specified in the console.

Moreover, please also pay attention to the

> ***Security Note:***
>
> The cache folder stores sensitive information that is not encrypted.
>   Therefore, you should make sure that only the service account of the
>   application tier (*TFSService*) has **Modify** permissions to this
>   folder.

Comment: I can't completely delete the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services_tfs_data\1e68059b-3328-4ab3-af6e-3a068be57a6d\Proxy" folder, because some ".pack" files are locked.
Which service should I stop to delete this folder?

Aniway, a lot of files have been deleted, but after the IISreset command, other files have been created.

Comment: Perfect, I have stopped the TFS Agent Service, and I was able to delete the old Proxy folder.

Comment: @magnum Glad to hear the issue fixed, thanks for your sharing.

Comment: unfortunately, even if I have deleted the folder, TFS started to save data again.

Comment: @magnum Have you tried to restart IIS server,  seems the process also include `Open a Command Prompt window, type iisreset, and then press ENTER.`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem updating TFS to the latest build (TFS 2015 Update 4).